# How to calculate rolling cumulative product on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, finance

I have a time series of returns, rolling beta, and rolling alpha in a pandas DataFrame.  How can I calculate a rolling annualized alpha for the alpha column of the DataFrame?  (I want to do the equivalent to =PRODUCT(1+[trailing 12 months])-1 in excel)

```
            SPX Index BBOEGEUS Index    Beta      Alpha
2006-07-31   0.005086    0.001910    1.177977   -0.004081
2006-08-31   0.021274    0.028854    1.167670    0.004012
2006-09-30   0.024566    0.009769    1.101618   -0.017293
2006-10-31   0.031508    0.030692    1.060355   -0.002717
2006-11-30   0.016467    0.031720    1.127585    0.013153
```

I was surprised to see that there was no "rolling" function built into pandas for this, but I was hoping somebody could help with a function that I can then apply to the df['Alpha'] column using pd.rolling_apply.

Thanks in advance for any help you have to offer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

will this do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your DataFrame; df = ...

pd.rolling_apply(df, 12, lambda x: np.prod(1 + x) - 1)
```

Comment: This function seems to be deprecated. There are more recent solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365545/calculating-cumulative-returns-with-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 31):

`rolling_apply` has been dropped in pandas and replaced by more versatile
[window methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#window-functions) (e.g. [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html#standard-moving-window-functions) etc.)

```py
# Both agg and apply will give you the same answer
(1+df).rolling(window=12).agg(np.prod) - 1
# BUT apply(raw=True) will be much FASTER!
(1+df).rolling(window=12).apply(np.prod, raw=True) - 1
```

Comment: is there any faster way?  maybe using `cumprod()` and dividing the last element in the window by the first element in the window?

Answer (score 8):

It will be a bit faster, if you move those +/-1 out of `df`, like this:

```
cumprod = (1.+df).rolling(window=12).agg(lambda x : x.prod()) -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by acumulating it all, and then getting the difference between the periods that you want:

```
(df+1).cumprod().pct_change(periods=12)
```

Answer (score -2):

rolling_apply is deprecated, so this works best:

> (1 + df).cumprod() - 1

Comment: This answer does not take into account the size of the rolling window - it assumes it to be 1.